# how does forever work with protractor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, protractor, forever

I came across a sample code where the unit tests were written in jasmine js and there was an added functionality of forever. But the forever monitor is invoked only after the browser session has been created.

myspec.js

```
var spec_config = require("./config.js").spec;
portNO = 5000;
console.log("going to forever");
spec_config.foreverMonitor(portN0);

driver.get(someUrl);

browser.getSession().then(function(session){
  console.log(session.id);
});

describe('..', function(){
  it('..',function(){...});
});
```

config.js

```
var spec = new function(){
  this.forever = require('forever');

  this.foreverMonitor = function(port){
   console.log("within forever");
   forever.list(false, function(err, data){
     console.log("inside forever.list");

     var child = new(forever.monitor)('app.js',{...});
      child.start();
      forever.startServer(child); 
   });
  };
}
module.exports={spec:spec};
```

Terminal:

```
going to forever
within forever
....session_id....
inside forever.list
```

I somehow don't seem to understand the flow of execution. Any ideas?

Comment: I get it that it is the asynchronous behaviour of javascript but I'd like to know the basis of such a behaviour. How does node manages this behaviour?